# Check whether arrays are equal

Tags: java, arrays, comparison, equality

How to check whether all elements in two arrays are the same?

How to make it return `true` if all values are the same?

I have tried different ways but couldn't succeed.

Comment: You have to compare the elements and `return false` if you find a pair of non identical elements or `return true` after all elements have been checked and found identical.

Comment: Why did you remove your code? Never edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 4):

Probably try something like this:

```
public static boolean checkIdentical(int[][] targetArray) {
    for (int i = 1; i < targetArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < targetArray[i].length; j++) {
            if (targetArray[i][j] != targetArray[0][j]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Caveat:**

If the arrays can have variable lengths like this:

```
int[][] identicalArray = {{3, 3, 3, 4}, {3, 3, 3}};
```

Then the condition will be:

```
if (targetArray[i].length != targetArray[0].length
        || targetArray[i][j] != targetArray[0][j]) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the use of `.. != targetArray[0][j]` force a lot of unnecessary lookups?

Comment: @RoyM what are unnecessary lookups?

Comment: @RoyM accessing `targetArray[0]` has O(1) time complexity. Since index-based arrays provide constant reads.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz Alright, got it. Thanks!

Comment: @RoyM You're most welcome!

Comment: I just tried this, and it didn't work. Maybe I put it somewhere wrong. I'm so tired. Ill try again tmmrw. Thanks for help.

Comment: @smoknovo Yes, sure. I have tested it, it works.

Answer (score 4):

You can do in a single loop with Arrays.equals() method.

```
public static boolean checkIdentical(int[][] targetArray) {
    int[] prev = null;
    for (int[] a : targetArray) {

        if (prev != null && !Arrays.equals(a, prev))
            return false;

        prev = a;
    }
    return true;
}
```

need to import java.util.Arrays.

Comment: But there will be a loop inside `Arrays.equals()`. So technically it isn't a single loop solution.

Comment: There should be an inside loop I suppose too. But why reinvent the wheel by writing the clumsy looping code again? Agreed that both might have same time complexity. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution here:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] identicalArray = { { 3, 3, 3 }, { 3, 3, 3 } };
    int[][] nonIdenticalArray = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 3, 2, 1 } };

    System.out.println("identicalArray all identical? " + checkIdentical(identicalArray));
    System.out.println("nonIdenticalArray all identical? " + checkIdentical(nonIdenticalArray));
}


public static boolean checkIdentical(int[][] targetArray) {
    int[] array1 = targetArray[0];
    for(int[] array : targetArray) {
        if (!Arrays.equals(array1, array))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**What happens in `checkIdentical` :**

- we receive a 2-dimensional `targetArray` in the parameter
- We store first 1-dimensional array of `targetArray` in array1. This will be our reference array which we will compare with each 1-dimensional array in `targetArray`
- We loop through each 1-dimensional array in `targetArray`and compare it with `array1`
- If a 1-dimensional array does not match our reference array `array1`, return `false`
- If we get to the end of the loop without encountering unequal 1-dimensional arrays, return `true`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and [`Arrays#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(int%5B%5D,int%5B%5D)) to write elegant 1 line `checkIdentical`:

```
public static boolean checkIdentical(int[][] targetArray) {
    return Stream.of(targetArray).allMatch(elm -> Arrays.equals(targetArray[0], elm));
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `Stream.of(targetArray)` supply a single element 
(`int[][]`) Stream?

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz It will supply a stream of array subarrays. You can [check it out](https://www.onlinegdb.com/S1rbbEucS) yourself.